# Where can i download latest stable bitcoin-core src files?

Tags: bitcoin-core, compiling

i want to download latest stable `bitcoin-core src` files. and want to `build` it on my system from `source`.

here is latest `src` of `bitcoin-core` but its not stable for production ready environment.

```
https://github.com/bitcoin/bitcoin
```

https://bitcoin.org/en/download shows latest version as

```
Latest version: 0.14.2
```

so where can i download `src files` of version `0.14.2`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Bitcoin Core source code is in a git repository. The repository has multiple branches and tags. The branches are source trees for a major version (e.g. 0.14 releases) and tags are for individual releases.

If you want to use the latest stable version of Bitcoin Core, run the following command:

```
git checkout v0.14.2
```

If you want to use the latest source for the 0.14 version series, use

```
git checkout 0.14
```

Answer (score 2):

As you can see [here](https://bitcoin.org/en/release/v0.14.2) the latest version is now the more stable version. As the most recent changes are for bug fixes, etc.

> This is a new minor version release, including various bugfixes and
>   performance improvements, as well as updated translations.

If you download a previous version this version may contain those fixed bugs.